# Laravel-método update de una clase hija

Tags: php, laravel

En mi proyecto cuento con una clase Patient, que hereda de User. Los métodos create y store de Patient son los siguientes y funcionan correctamente:

**Create-PatientController**

```
public function create()
{
    //
return view('patients/create');
}
```

**Store-PatientController**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  //dd($request["DNI"]);
    //
    $data = new User();

    $data->email = $request['email'];
    $data->password = $request['password'];
    $data->name = $request['name'];
    $data->surnames = $request['surnames'];

    $data->phone= $request['phone'];
    $data->gender=$request['gender'];
    $data->admin= (bool)$request['admin'];
    $data->save();



    $patient = new Patient();

    $patient->DNI= $request['DNI'];
    $patient->birthdate= $request['birthdate'];
    $patient->address= $request['address'];
    $patient->nationality=$request['nationality'];

    $patient->user_id = $data->id;
    $patient->save();

    return Redirect::to('patients');
}
```

**Mi método Edit**:

```
public function edit(Request $request)
{

    //dd($speciality);

    $patient = Patient::findOrFail($request->id);
    return view('patients/edit')->with('patient', $patient);


}
```

**Y mi método Update**

```
  public function update(Request $request)
{
    //

    $patient = Patient::findOrFail($request->id);
    $this->validate($request,[

      'DNI' => 'required',
      'birthdate' => 'required',
      'address' => 'required',
      'nationality' => 'required',

    ]);
    $input = $request->all();

    $patient->fill($input)->save();

    return Redirect::to('patients');


}
```

Tal y como están estos dos últimos métodos, se actualizan solamente los campos de Patient. No sé como podría actualizar los campos de usuario: probé a hacer edit de la siguiente forma:

```
public function edit(Request $request)
   {

//dd($speciality);
$user = User::findOrFail($request->id);
$patient = Patient::findOrFail($request->id);
return view('patients/edit')->with('patient', $patient)->with('user',$user);


     }
```

Pero entonces pensé que realmente no haría falta hacer la línea `$user = User::findOrFail($request->id);` ya que la clase Patient cuenta con la propiedad user_id. No sé muy bien cómo seguir con estos dos métodos, así que agradecería una pequeña orientación al respecto.

Comment: ¿el id de patient y de user es el mismo siempre? Según lo que veo en tu código al final.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el Modelo **`Patient`**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
}
```

En el método **`edit`** del Controlador
***Opción 1***

```
public function edit(Request $request)
{
    $patient = Patient::findOrFail($request->id);
    $user = $patient->user;
    return view('patients/edit')->with('patient', $patient)->with('user',$user);
}
```

***Opción 2***

```
public function edit(Request $request)
{
    $patient = Patient::findOrFail($request->id)->with('user');
    return view('patients/edit')->with('patient', $patient);
    // en la vista podés acceder a los datos del usuario 
    // haciendo por ejemplo $patient->user->name
}
```

**Para actualizar los datos del usuario**

Podrías hacer algo como

```
$patient = Patient::findOrFail($request->id);

$patient->user()->update($request->all());
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha ayudado bastante

Comment: De nada. Me alegro!